# Discord.js var with username outputs "undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (message.reactions.size) {
    let reaction = message.reactions.find(r => r._emoji.name == '');
    if (reaction) {
    var winnaar = reaction.users.random;

  }
}
```

So this is for a discord.js giveaway bot, and what its meant to do is store a random users name who reacted in the "winnaar" (winner in dutch) variable. But when I make the bot send a message containing ${winnaar} it outputs "Undifined". I am quite new to Discord js and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link [Discord random](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=random)

Here you can see that random is function, try with random(1)

Comment: I tried this but it still outputted undefined when i send a messge.

Comment: Huh, i tried this and everything is working..Can you provide us code?

Comment: did you try to console log reaction?